# How do I validate data mapping between 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-mapping

I am trying to validate a data mapping between two data frames for specific columns. I need to validate the following:

1. if values in a specific column in df1 matches the mapping in a specific column in df2.
2. if values in a specific column in df1 does not match the specified mapping in a specific column in df2 - a different value in df2.
3. if values in a specific column in df1 does not have a match in in df2.

df1 looks like this:

| cp_id | cp_code |
| --- | --- |
| 2A23 | A |
| 2A24 | D |
| 3A45 | G |
| 7A96 | B |
| 2A30 | R |
| 6A18 | K |

df2 looks like like:

| cp_type_id | cp_type_code |
| --- | --- |
| 2A23 | 8 |
| 2A24 | 7 |
| 3A45 | 3 |
| 2A44 | 1 |
| 6A18 | 8 |
| 4A08 | 2 |

The data mapping constitutes of sets of values where the combination could match any values within the set, as following:

- ('A','C','F','K','M') in df1 should map to (2, 8) in df2 - either 2 or 8
- ('B') in df1 should map to 4 in df2
- ('D','G','I') in df1 should map to 7 in df2
- ('T','U') in df1 should map to (3,5) in df2 - either 3 or 5

Note that df1 has a cp_code as R which is not mapped and that 3A45 is a mismatch. The good news is there is a unique identifier key to use.

First, I created a list for each mapping set and created a statement using merge to check for each mapping. I ended up with 3 lists and 3 statements per set, which I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

At the end I want to combine the matches into one df that I call match, all no_matches into another df that I call no_match, and all no_mappings into another df that I call no_mapping, like the following:

**Match**

| cp_id | cp_code | cp_type_id | cp_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2A23 | A | 2A23 | 8 |
| 2A24 | D | 2A24 | 7 |
| 6A18 | K | 6A18 | 8 |

**Mismatch**

| cp_id | cp_code | cp_type_id | cp_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3A45 | G | 3A45 | 3 |

**No Mapping**

| cp_id | cp_code | cp_type_id | cp_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7A96 | B | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 2A44 | 1 |
| 2A30 | R | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 4A08 | 2 |

I am having a hard time to make the no_match to work.
This is what I tried for no match:

1. filtered df1 based on the set 2 codes
2. filtered df2 based on not in map 2 codes
3. for the no mapping, I did a df merge with on='cp_id'

```
    no_mapping_set2 = df1_filtered.merge(df2_filtered, on='cp_id', indicator = True)
```

With the code above, for cp_id = 'B', for example, instead of getting only 1 row back, I get a lot of duplicate rows with cp_id = 'B'.

Just to state my level, I am a beginner in Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time.

Rob

Comment: can you add the expected output?

Comment: Thank you, Nk03. I added the expected output

Comment: As I understand what you are trying to do is to create three different dataframes a df_match, df_mismatch, and df_nomatch from the two input dataframes df1 and df2 using the rules defined above?  Is this correct?

Comment: itprorh66, I edited my post to include this info.